# CFPreferences to /Library/Preferences

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, core-foundation, cfpreferences

I have a prefpane used in System Preferences (With the authorization lock). I need to get my preferences to write to `/Library/Preferences`. However, whenever I try to synchronize the prefs to `kCFPreferencesAnyUser` and `kCFPreferencesCurrentHost` it just fails out even if my lock is unlocked. Is there any way to write my preferences to `/Library/Preferences` without creating a helper application? I would want to avoid that because it's redundant.

> Note that to modify “Any User” preferences requires root privileges (or Admin privileges prior to Mac OS X v10.6)—see [*Authorization Services Programming Guide.*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995)

I read the authorization services programming guide and it did not even mention preferences.

Answer (score 1):

CFPreferences uses your process's euid to determine what "current user" means. You could possibly set your euid to 0, but that's really not recommended because it means your *whole program* is now a possible source of privilege escalation attacks if it contains a vulnerability, rather than just a tiny purpose-specific helper. That's bad for your users, and by extension bad for you.

Also, XPC and seteuid() don't always play nice, and CFPreferences uses XPC. Switching from euid 0 to non-0 should work, I believe, but I wouldn't count on the other direction working.