# Writing to `/Library/Preferences` on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, cocoa, io, permissions

I'm writing a Java app that I'm compiling into a `.app`. I want to write to the system-wide preferences folder in `/Library/Preferences`, but I can't seem to write there; I assume it's a permissions thing. In what circumstances is an app allowed to write to the "root" Library folder? Where else should I put system-specific (rather than user-specific) config data on OS X?

Comment: When I've had to write files into a system-wide preference file (e.g. [using CFPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454957/cfpreferences-to-library-preferences)), I've had to do it as a root or admin-priviledged helper tool.  I only know how to do this natively and not as a Java app, tho.

Comment: Yeah, the [App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html) wasn't terribly useful either: it just said "you should never have to write to these folders; just write to the one in the user's home". Is there anywhere on the filesystem that can be both read and written-to by every user for something like a config file?