# How to store session value common to all system users in OS X

Tags: macos, session, nsuserdefaults, cfpreferences

In my mac OS X application, i have used NSUserDefaults to store values in session.  This NSUserDefaults keep the session values only for respective system level users. But now i want to use session value that is common for all system level users. If i store a session value from admin, it should be accessed by any system users(For Ex: Guest User).

Suggest your answers to achieve this.

**EDITED CONTENT:**

I have used CFPreferences to store the session value for all system users the in reference with the michael's answer.

**Code:**

To save values in CFPreferences

```
 CFStringRef appID = CFSTR("com.company.test");
    CFStringRef textColorKey = CFSTR("test123");
    CFStringRef colorBLUE = CFSTR("BLUE");
    CFPreferencesSetValue (textColorKey,
                           colorBLUE,
                           appID,
                           kCFPreferencesAnyUser,
                           kCFPreferencesCurrentHost
                           );

    CFPreferencesSynchronize(appID,
                             kCFPreferencesAnyUser,
                             kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
```

To retrieve from CFPreferences

```
CFStringRef textColorKey = CFSTR("test123");
CFStringRef textColor;
// Read the preference.
CFStringRef appID = CFSTR("com.company.test");

textColor = (CFStringRef)CFPreferencesCopyValue(textColorKey,
                                                appID,
                                                kCFPreferencesAnyUser,
                                                kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
```

But it always retrieve nil value. Please point out what i am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

If you look within the [first few paragraphs of the NSUserDefaults documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSUserDefaults), you'll see this tidbit:

> The NSUserDefaults class does not currently support per-host
>   preferences. To do this, you must use the CFPreferences API (see
>   Preferences Utilities Reference). However, NSUserDefaults correctly
>   reads per-host preferences, so you can safely mix CFPreferences code
>   with NSUserDefaults code.

CFPreferences *does* have a [`kCFPreferencesAnyUser` key](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Application_Host_and_User_Keys), but it's also a [pain in the rear end to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454957/cfpreferences-to-library-preferences) for what you are trying to do.  Other people have suggested [workarounds that involve hiding files in locations that are readable and writable to all users on the machine](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/107482-global-preferences-using-cfpreferences.html), but if you really want to do this right, you'd need to come up with a solution that involves [writing a separate tool (which gets root/admin privileges) that sets these privileges, called via SMJobBless from your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134841/writing-a-privileged-helper-tool-with-smjobbless).

Comment: Please have a look at my edited content. what i am missing there?